# DataList and Enter Key Event

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have an input text field on which I trigger key event. On enter, i process some specific code with the input value. All works great.

**HAML:**

```
%input#myField{:type => "text"}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
my_field = document.getElementById('myField');

my_field.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (tag_field.value.length != 0) {
            console.log(my_field.value);
            // Run my specific process with my_field.value 
            my_field.value = '';
        }
    }
}, false);
```

But now I want to add datalist on this input.

**HAML:**

```
%input#myField{:list => "htmlList", :type => "text"}
%datalist#htmlList
    %option{:value => "toto"} toto
    %option{:value => "foo"} foo
```

The problem is when I navigate on datalist to select an item, I press the enter key. 
On enter key, my listener is called and processes my code with the initial value of input.
At this step, the value of the field is empty. After, the value is replaced by the value selected in the datalist.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to change the behaviour of the datalist to replace the input value by the datalist selected value without pressing enter key? (Disable enter key for datalist)
- Is there a way to detect when the datalist is active (or visible) to process a different behaviour in my EventListener ?

Comment: are we talking about something like this? http://davidwalsh.name/demo/datalist.php

Comment: Yes. For exemple : after typing "mo", i select an element in the list and validate typing enter. At these step, i trigger my listener but the input value is still "mo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Keypress` event will be fired after you press the key but before the data is registered into the field.
`Keyup` event will be fired after you press the key but after the data is registered into the field

**HTML:**

```
<input list="browsers" id="myField"/>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

**JS:**

```
var my_field = document.getElementById('myField');

      my_field.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              event.preventDefault();

              if (my_field.value.length != 0) {
                  console.log(my_field.value);
                  // Run my specific process with my_field.value 
                  my_field.value = '';
              }
          }
      }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5p6FZ/

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent keyup event completely?